# Tetris game in C: Function for moving blocks down enters an infinite loop and doesn't make the blocks fall down correctly

Tags: c, infinite-loop, tetris

I'm writing a Tetris game for my 1st year computer science project and I have a problem with the function which shifts blocks downwards. I represent my game state as a 2d array in a following way (example of a square Tetromino):

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I would like the function to cause the following change to the game state:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0
```

However, rather than shifting the block down until it reaches the last row and then exiting the while loop, it doesn't exit the while loop at all.

Here is the function which is supposed to make the block shift down:

```
void block_falling(int gamestate[NO_BLOCKS_FOR_GAP][NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS_HORIZONTALLY])
{
    int temporary_storage;

    bool is_falling = true;

    while (is_falling)
    {
        for (int row_counter = 0; row_counter < NO_BLOCKS_FOR_GAP; row_counter++)
        {
            for (int column_counter = 0; column_counter < NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS_HORIZONTALLY; column_counter++)
            {
                if ((gamestate[row_counter][column_counter] == 1) || (gamestate[row_counter][column_counter] == 2))
                {
                    if (row_counter != NO_BLOCKS_FOR_GAP - 1)
                    {
                        temporary_storage = gamestate[row_counter][column_counter];
                        gamestate[row_counter][column_counter] = gamestate[row_counter - 1][column_counter];
                        gamestate[row_counter - 1][column_counter] = temporary_storage;
                    }
                    if (row_counter == NO_BLOCKS_FOR_GAP - 1)
                    {
                        is_falling = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the part of code responsible for shifting the blocks down is correct, as when I copy the code below for example 10 times, the blocks shifts down 10 by ten blocks.

```
for (int row_counter = 0; row_counter < NO_BLOCKS_FOR_GAP; row_counter++)
{
    for (int column_counter = 0; column_counter < NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS_HORIZONTALLY; column_counter++)
    {
        if ((gamestate[row_counter][column_counter] == 1) || (gamestate[row_counter][column_counter] == 2))
        {
            temporary_storage = gamestate[row_counter][column_counter];
            gamestate[row_counter][column_counter] = gamestate[row_counter - 1][column_counter];
            gamestate[row_counter - 1][column_counter] = temporary_storage;
        }
    }
}
```

How should I fix the function so that it transfers the block downwards until it reaches the bottom row?

Comment: Each repetition of the loop you have extracted shifts the piece down. Now please *write down* answers to these two questions. (1) When should you stop shifting the piece down? (2) What condition does the expression `row_counter == NO_BLOCKS_FOR_GAP - 1` represent?

Comment: @n. m. 1)The piece should stop shifting when the bottom 1s or 2s of the shifting block reach the bottom row of the array. The expression row_counter == NO_BLOCKS_FOR_GAP - 1 is supposed to represent the index of the bottom row of the array.

Comment: It looks like you are confused as to which direction is up. Your piece moves towards the *smaller row indices*, so smaller is down and index 0 must be the bottom row.

Comment: @n.m. Okay, so if I change row_counter == NO_BLOCKS_FOR_GAP - 1 to row_counter == 0 in the if statement the code should shift the block correctly?

Comment: The loop will stop but it still won't be correct (you should try and see what you get).

Comment: You will get through your course much more successfully by learning to use a debugger.  You should IMO be introduced to a source-level symbolic debugger the day you wrote your first C code.  Beyond that note that the two `if` blocks in your inner loop are mutually exclusive, so an `if-else` would be a better choice - you don't need two tests.